# Remove scientific notation in p value

Tags: r, regression, scientific-notation

Is there a way to automatically display p value without scientific notation in regression models?

For instance

```
library(cobalt)
library(WeightIt)
data("lalonde", package = "cobalt")

W.out <- weightit(treat ~ age + educ + race + nodegree + re74 + re75,
                  data = lalonde, estimand = "ATT", method = "ps")

library(survey)
d.w <- svydesign(~1, weights = W.out$weights, data = lalonde)
fit <- svyglm(married ~ treat, design = d.w, family="poisson") 
coef(summary(fit))
exp(coefficients(fit))
exp(confint.default(fit))
```

What can I add to the code to show the p value without the scientific notation automatically? I don't want to convert every time
[image]

Comment: Try `format` with `scientific=FALSE`, e.g. `type.convert(format(t.test(sample(100, 20)), scientific=F), as.is=F)`

Comment: If you want to remove scientific notation throughout your whole script, add `options(scipen=999)` at the top of the document.

Comment: Do you want to modify the console output or are you exporting to some other format?

Comment: @dufei I would like to modify the console output